# Refactor tree controller which works with many different types

Tags: c#, tree, refactoring

I'm refactoring a class (Controller) which handles a tree. Because there are many different types (around 20) in the tree. It uses often following structure to handle for example an insertion:

1. Determine type of the object
2. Do some type specific things and insert object into tree

   ```
   public void AddChildren(Animal animal)
   {
       var cat = animal as Cat;
       if (cat != null)
       {
           AddCat(cat);
           return;
       }

       var dog = animal as Dog;
       if (dog != null)
       {
           AddDog(dog);
           return;
       }
   }

   public void AddCat(Cat cat)
   {
       //do some cat specific things
       //add to tree
   }
   ```

So the logic for determining the type of an object is used in many places within the class. Is there a good approach to concentrate this logic in one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the Strategy(GoF) pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

1. Create an interface *LivingAnimal* with a method *addToTree(Tree tree)*
2. Implement this interface in objects *Cat*, *Dog*, etc.
3. in *Cat.addToTree(Tree tree)* (and other objects), do your cat specific stuff, and add itself in the tree (*tree.add(this)*)
4. In your controller, create a method *addChildren(LivingAnimal p)*. This method finds the correct type of object (Cat, Dog, etc.) and calls *addToTree(tree)* on it.

When you're using Strategy(GoF), you're delegating the responsibility to the right object. In this case, you'll simplify your controller and keep a high cohesion on the various objects.

Comment: Thanks, nice suggestion. But unfortunately I cannot change the objects which are placed in the tree. They come from a library which I cannot change.

Comment: What about creating a Proxy(GoF) for each objects, and applying Strategy on the proxy?

Here's the Proxy pattern:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern .
If you decide to use Proxy(GoF) on a library, you are also protecting yourself against a modification of the library.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. If I get enough time from my boss ;). I will try it with the proxy and state pattern.